# How to get values if more than one json field has same name in the dictionary?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have this JSON with response having more than one field with same key value name, how can I access those? I am using Codable in swift and I can access the first "value" from "pricingInfo" but how do I access the other pricingInfo s ?

```
"fareComponentList":[  
   {  
      "passengerFareInfoList":[  
         {  
            "passengerTypeQuantity":{  
               "passengerType":{  
                  "code":"CHLD"
               },
               "quantity":1,
               "hasStrecher":false
            },
            "pricingInfo":{  
               "baseFare":{  
                  "amount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":45
                  }
               },
               "fees":{  
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":0
                  }
               },
               "totalFare":{  
                  "amount":{  
                     "accountingSign":"ADC",
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":72
                  }
               },
               "fareConstruction":"",
               "passengerTypeCode":"CHLD",
               "surcharges":{  
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":24
                  },
                  "surchargeList":[  
                     {  
                        "surchargeAmount":{  
                           "currency":{  
                              "code":"USD"
                           },
                           "value":24
                        },
                        "surchargeCode":"YQ",
                        "surchargeType":"S",
                        "paid":false
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "taxes":{  
                  "taxList":[  
                     {  
                        "paid":false,
                        "taxAmount":{  
                           "currency":{  
                              "code":"USD"
                           },
                           "value":1
                        },
                        "taxCode":"AF",
                        "taxType":"T"
                     },
                     {  
                        "paid":false,
                        "taxAmount":{  
                           "currency":{  
                              "code":"USD"
                           },
                           "value":2
                        },
                        "taxCode":"M5",
                        "taxType":"T"
                     }
                  ],
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":3
                  }
               },
               "discountApplied":false,
               "fareBaggageAllowance":0
            },
            "fareInfoList":[  
               {  
                  "cabinClassCode":"Y",
                  "fareReferenceCode":"x",
                  "flightSegmentSequence":1,
                  "fareReferenceName":"x",
                  "fareGroupName":"x",
                  "resBookDesigCode":"S",
                  "fareReferenceID":"x"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "passengerTypeQuantity":{  
               "passengerType":{  
                  "code":"ADLT"
               },
               "quantity":1,
               "hasStrecher":false
            },
            "pricingInfo":{  
               "baseFare":{  
                  "amount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":60
                  }
               },
               "fees":{  
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":0
                  }
               },
               "totalFare":{  
                  "amount":{  
                     "accountingSign":"ADC",
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":87
                  }
               },
               "fareConstruction":"",
               "passengerTypeCode":"ADLT",
               "surcharges":{  
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":24
                  },
                  "surchargeList":[  
                     {  
                        "surchargeAmount":{  
                           "currency":{  
                              "code":"USD"
                           },
                           "value":24
                        },
                        "surchargeCode":"YQ",
                        "surchargeType":"S",
                        "paid":false
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "taxes":{  
                  "taxList":[  
                     {  
                        "paid":false,
                        "taxAmount":{  
                           "currency":{  
                              "code":"USD"
                           },
                           "value":1
                        },
                        "taxCode":"AF",
                        "taxType":"T"
                     },
                     {  
                        "paid":false,
                        "taxAmount":{  
                           "currency":{  
                              "code":"USD"
                           },
                           "value":2
                        },
                        "taxCode":"M5",
                        "taxType":"T"
                     }
                  ],
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":3
                  }
               },
               "discountApplied":false,
               "fareBaggageAllowance":0
            },
            "fareInfoList":[  
               {  
                  "cabinClassCode":"Y",
                  "fareReferenceCode":"x",
                  "flightSegmentSequence":1,
                  "fareReferenceName":"x",
                  "fareGroupName":"x",
                  "resBookDesigCode":"S",
                  "fareReferenceID":"x"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "passengerTypeQuantity":{  
               "passengerType":{  
                  "code":"INFT"
               },
               "quantity":1,
               "hasStrecher":false
            },
            "pricingInfo":{  
               "baseFare":{  
                  "amount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":6
                  }
               },
               "fees":{  
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":0
                  }
               },
               "totalFare":{  
                  "amount":{  
                     "accountingSign":"ADC",
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":6
                  }
               },
               "fareConstruction":"",
               "passengerTypeCode":"INFT",
               "surcharges":{  
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":0
                  }
               },
               "taxes":{  
                  "totalAmount":{  
                     "currency":{  
                        "code":"USD"
                     },
                     "value":0
                  }
               },
               "discountApplied":false,
               "fareBaggageAllowance":0
            },
            "fareInfoList":[  
               {  
                  "cabinClassCode":"Y",
                  "fareReferenceCode":"x",
                  "flightSegmentSequence":1,
                  "fareReferenceName":"x",
                  "fareGroupName":"x",
                  "resBookDesigCode":"S",
                  "fareReferenceID":"x"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "pricingOverview":{  
         "totalTax":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":"USD"
            },
            "value":6
         },
         "totalAmount":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":"USD"
            },
            "value":165
         },
         "totalPenalty":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":""
            },
            "value":0
         },
         "totalBaseFare":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":"USD"
            },
            "value":111
         },
         "equivTotalAmountList":[  
            {  
               "accountingSign":"ADC",
               "currency":{  
                  "code":""
               },
               "value":0
            }
         ],
         "totalSurcharge":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":"USD"
            },
            "value":48
         },
         "totalDiscount":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":""
            },
            "value":0
         },
         "totalServiceCharge":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":""
            },
            "value":0
         },
         "totalOtherFee":{  
            "accountingSign":"ADC",
            "currency":{  
               "code":""
            },
            "value":0
         }
      }
   }
]
```

What I am trying to do is, store the "value" from each

```
"pricingInfo":{  
   "baseFare":{  
      "amount":{  
         "currency":{  
            "code":"USD"
         },
         "value":45
      };
```

How can I do it?(Basically I'm trying to get the price value of Adult, child and infant)

Comment: you need to refactor your json, it's unreadable

Comment: @Alastar Sorry,changed it

Comment: Use a dictionary or your own custom struct in an array.

Comment: If you have already parsed the JSON and decoded your models (since the root object is a list) then you just iterate `passengerFareInfoList` and your values would be at keypath: `pricingInfo.totalFare.amount.value`

Comment: @Alladinian But that only goes to the first instance of "value" , I can get that value, but I want to get the other "value" fields in the Json.(or if am wrong can you point me in the right direction? or maybe a sample code?

Comment: If the object is an array `[]` and contains multiple objects you have to use a loop to iterate the array (`for item in array { ... }`), rather than the `first` syntax which considers – as the name implies – only the *first* item. Please read [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) in the Swift Language Guide, that's very basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your JSON, this can be your codable models.

```
typealias FareComponentList = [FareComponentListElement]

struct FareComponentListElement: Codable {
    let passengerFareInfoList: [PassengerFareInfoList]
    let pricingOverview: PricingOverview
}

struct PassengerFareInfoList: Codable {
    let passengerTypeQuantity: PassengerTypeQuantity
    let pricingInfo: PricingInfo
    let fareInfoList: [FareInfoList]
}

struct FareInfoList: Codable {
    let cabinClassCode, fareReferenceCode: String
    let flightSegmentSequence: Int
    let fareReferenceName, fareGroupName, resBookDesigCode, fareReferenceID: String
}

struct PassengerTypeQuantity: Codable {
    let passengerType: Currency
    let quantity: Int
    let hasStrecher: Bool
}

struct Currency: Codable {
    let code: Code
}

enum Code: String, Codable {
    case adlt = "ADLT"
    case chld = "CHLD"
    case empty = ""
    case inft = "INFT"
    case usd = "USD"
}

struct PricingInfo: Codable {
    let baseFare: BaseFare
    let fees: Fees
    let totalFare: TotalFare
    let fareConstruction: String
    let passengerTypeCode: Code
    let surcharges: Surcharges
    let taxes: Taxes
    let discountApplied: Bool
    let fareBaggageAllowance: Int
}

struct BaseFare: Codable {
    let amount: Amount
}

struct Amount: Codable {
    let currency: Currency
    let value: Int
}

struct Fees: Codable {
    let totalAmount: Amount
}

struct Surcharges: Codable {
    let totalAmount: Amount
    let surchargeList: [SurchargeList]?
}

struct SurchargeList: Codable {
    let surchargeAmount: Amount
    let surchargeCode, surchargeType: String
    let paid: Bool
}

struct Taxes: Codable {
    let taxList: [TaxList]?
    let totalAmount: Amount
}

struct TaxList: Codable {
    let paid: Bool
    let taxAmount: Amount
    let taxCode, taxType: String
}

struct TotalFare: Codable {
    let amount: TotalAmount
}

struct TotalAmount: Codable {
    let accountingSign: AccountingSign
    let currency: Currency
    let value: Int
}

enum AccountingSign: String, Codable {
    case adc = "ADC"
}

struct PricingOverview: Codable {
    let totalTax, totalAmount, totalPenalty, totalBaseFare: TotalAmount
    let equivTotalAmountList: [TotalAmount]
    let totalSurcharge, totalDiscount, totalServiceCharge, totalOtherFee: TotalAmount
}
```

Using the above models, following values can be accessed.

```
let passengerType = fareComponentList[0].passengerFareInfoList[0].passengerTypeQuantity.passengerType // ADLT / CHLD / INFT
let amount = fareComponentList[0].passengerFareInfoList[0].pricingInfo.baseFare.amount.value
```

Comment: I copy pasted your entire code, I got Use of unresolved identifier 'fareComponentList'; did you mean 'FareComponentList'? This error,i replaced it.

then I get another error "nstance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type 'FareComponentList' (aka 'Array<FareComponentListElement>')"

Comment: The last two lines is just an idea for you. It is not a compiled code. If subscript cannot be accessed, iterate over the array and retrieve the values.

Comment: Thank you, this lets me access the first values. passengerType -> ADLT and value -> 60. But my question was how do I access passengerType ->CHLD and its value?

since the everything inside passengerFareInfoList isn't an array therefore no subscripting.

Comment: how can I get values from the second dictionary and the third dictionary from the passengerFareInfoList array?